# Simple hypothesis testing problem Beta distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing

Let $X$ be a random variable that is Beta distributed with parameters $\alpha=\beta=\theta>0$, so the given frequency function is

$f(x|\theta)=\dfrac{\Gamma(2\theta)}{\Gamma(\theta)^2}x^{\theta-1}(1-x)^{\theta-1}1_{(0,1)}(x)$.

Where $\Gamma(\theta)$ is the gamma function.
I want to test $H_0:\theta=1$ against $H_1:\theta=2$. With the LR-test I found that you reject $H_0$ for large values of $X(1-X)$. Now I'm supposed to show that we should reject the null hypothesis for values of  $X$ within the interval $[1/2-c,1/2+c]$ for a certain $c$ (constant) that is later determined. Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: $y = x(1 - x)$ is a parabola, which opening downward, and have the axis of symmetry at $x = 1/2$. So it has a global maximum at the vertex. If $x(1 - x)$ is large, then $x$ must be located within a neighborhood of $1/2$. If you are not getting this yet, you should try to draw it out to visualize it.

Comment: @BGM Thanks, very clear explanation. Was thinking way to complicated :)